# ERROR ITMS-90432: Invalid Swift Support. Is there a solution?

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, compiler-errors

Getting an error when trying to distribute my app to App Store Connect. This is the first time I've had this error. I've distributed 8 different builds of the app already without error. Full error is:

> ERROR ITMS-90432: "Invalid Swift Support. The file {APP NAME}/Frameworks/AppFrameworkInfo.plist doesn’t have the correct file type for this location. Ensure you’re using the correct file, rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode, and resubmit it."

I've taken a look around online but I can't seem to find any working solution. This is a Flutter app.

Is there any known solution? Am I missing something obvious?

EDIT: **SOLUTION** [Solved by edford on the Apple Developer forums. Delete AppFrameworkInfo.plist from the /Frameworks folder of your build before distribution.](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/669948)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

SOLUTION [Solved by edford on the Apple Developer forums. Delete AppFrameworkInfo.plist from the /Frameworks folder of your build before distribution](https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/669948)