# ITMS-90432: Issue while uploading app to appstore

Tags: ios, xcode, frameworks, app-store-connect-api

We are trying to upload new build for our already existing app to appstore, with a build script to embed framework(Which is just copying from build directory to MyApp.app/Frameworks). Everything builds and works fine in my local machine. But getting this error while uploading to appstore.

> ITMS-90432: Invalid Swift Support - The file
> MyApp.app/Frameworks/Framework1.framework,
> MyApp.app/Frameworks/Framework2.framework doesn’t have the correct
> file type for this location. Ensure you’re using the correct file,
> rebuild your app using the current public (GM) version of Xcode, and
> resubmit it.

We are copying to the correct directory, but still getting the above error while uploading.

We found similar issue [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65387684/error-itms-90432-invalid-swift-support-is-there-a-solution). But there it was obvious that info.plist file is in wrong location. But in our case its in the correct location.

Attaching the script we are using. This we are adding in run script in build phase.

```
frameworks_used_in_extensions=("Framework1" "Framework2")

# Loop over the array
for MODULE in "${frameworks_used_in_extensions[@]}"
do
    export LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS="${LIBRARY_SEARCH_PATHS}":"${SDKROOT}/${MODULE}.framework/"
    cp -Rv "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${MODULE}.framework" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/Frameworks/"
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY_FOR_ITEMS="${EXPANDED_CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY_NAME}"
    if [ "${CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY_FOR_ITEMS}" = "" ] ; then
        CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY_FOR_ITEMS="${CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY}"
    fi
    codesign --force --verbose --sign "${CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY_FOR_ITEMS}" "${BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR}/${PRODUCT_NAME}.app/Frameworks/${MODULE}.framework/${MODULE}"
        
done
```

Comment: It seems you put 2 file names in a field that must contains only one

Comment: @PtitXav i just shared the script above. Suggest me any findings.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can create an `alias`/`shortcut` of the embedded frameworks. Hence they are not the correct file types under `MyApp.app/Frameworks/`

use the following to make a proper copy of the frameworks

```
cp -r pathToSource.framework pathToDestination.framework
```